# CIFilter generated image does not display in IB or on simulator

Tags: ios, uiimage, ciimage

When generating an image with CIFilter, all is displayed correctly on a physical device but will not display in simulator or in IB.

**Here is the code that I'm using to render the image:**

```
if let f = constructFilter(radius: radius, value: sliderView.value.hsba.brightness), let foi = f.outputImage {
   circleView.image = UIImage(ciImage: foi)
}
```

**And the construct filter function is:**

```
private func constructFilter(radius: CGFloat, value: CGFloat) -> CIFilter? {
       guard let cs = CGColorSpace.init(name: CGColorSpace.extendedSRGB) else { return nil }
       return CIFilter(name: "CIHueSaturationValueGradient", parameters: [
        "inputColorSpace" : cs,
        "inputDither" : 0,
        "inputRadius" : radius,
        "inputSoftness" : 0,
        "inputValue" : value])
}
```

The 'value' input parameter to constructFilter is always 1.0, BTW.

Of course, if I create the image from a resource, it works fine on device, simulator and IB. But that isn't what I need to do.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Regards,
ac

*** Editing original question as I can't add comments with code snippet ***
I solved the problem by changing the rendering function thus:

```
        if let f = constructFilter(radius: radius, brightness: sliderView.value.hsba.brightness), let foi = f.outputImage {
        #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
        let context = CIContext()
        if let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(foi, from: foi.extent) {
            circleView.image = UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage)
        }
        #else
        circleView.image = UIImage(ciImage: foi)
        #endif
    }
```

Both @Matt and @Gigi identified the solution but I won't upvote their answers since neither commented on the root of the problem - both are "X doesn't work so do Y" - I am still not clear as to why IB/Simulator needs different code.  Also neither answer conveyed the fact that this is an IB/Simulator issue only

Comment: What does "will not display" mean?

Comment: The question being asked by Rucksack is a completely different question. Whether the answer resolves to the same thing is irrelevant...

Answer (score 2):

UIImage is only a container for image data, if your image is created using a CIImage your UIImage has no CGImage data and will not be rendered in your simulator view. In order to work correctly in the simulator you need a CGImage.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(foi.extent.size)
let cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

let myCIContext:CIContext = CIContext(cgContext: cgContext, options: nil)
let outCGimage:CGImage = myCIContext.createCGImage(foi, from: foi.extent)!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

imgView?.image = UIImage(cgImage: outCGimage)
```

Comment: "UIImage is only a container for image data, if your image is created using a CIImage your UIImage has no CGImage data and will not be rendered in your simulator view" - then how does it get rendered on a device?